# Jquery - Hide specific div

Tags: jquery, html, hide

I have several divs that share a common class. If one of these divs do **not** have a child div, I want to hide the div. I can find the right div but I'm unable to hide it.

This is my code,

```
$(function() {

        if ($(".adRight.childen('div')").length == 0) {
            $(this).hide();

        }

    });
```

What should I use instead of (this)? this refers to the document and not the div the if-statement found.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're looking for:

```
$("div.adRight:not(:has(div))").hide();
```

Does how it reads.

Your original code confused selectors with functions (eg, `.childen` is treated as a class selector), and shows you need to read a little more before writhing jQuery code. Sorry.
Your `if` statement, for example, is looking for something jQuery cannot find (wrong syntax). jQuery returns an empty collection - it has a policy not to throw unneeded exceptions, so its length is 0. It does not look for 0 children.
Also, note that for a simple action like `hide` you don't need to iterate the collection - `hide` will work with the elements you've already found, using your selector.

Comment: Thank you Kobi! Very nice and efficient code. :)

Have I understood this correctly,

- div.adRight refers to all divs with class adRight?
- :not and :has checks if it does not have a div?

Comment: Jova - correct. jQuery's selectors are very powerful, but easy to work with, and readable. You just have to find the right one!

Answer (score 0):

Maybe:

if ($(".adRight div")== undefined) {
            $(".adRight").hide();
        }

(~~not sure)